# Getting certain values from one column in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's take well known data set - flights.

I want to have 10 flights with biggest as well as lowest feature arr_time.

I tried to do it in such way :

```
library(dplyr)
#Highest values

flights %>%
  group_by(air_time) %>%
  top_n(10, air_time)

#Smallest values 
flights %>%
group_by(air_time) %>%
top_n(-10,air_time)
```

However the problem is that I get something very strange.  These two results are identical. I thought that it might be problem with using `group_by` but its also not working without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the slice_min/_max function from dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)

data(flights)

#Largest values 
flights %>%
  dplyr::slice_max(order_by = arr_time, n = 10)

#Smallest values 
flights %>%
  dplyr::slice_min(order_by = arr_time, n = 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want top 10 values by `arr_time` you should not group by it. Try :

```
library(dplyr)

flights %>% 
  top_n(10, air_time) %>%
  select(air_time) %>%
  arrange(air_time)

#   air_time
#      <dbl>
# 1      671
# 2      671
# 3      675
# 4      676
# 5      676
# 6      679
# 7      683
# 8      686
# 9      686
#10      691
#11      695
```

and

```
flights %>% 
  top_n(-10, air_time) %>%
  select(air_time) %>%
  arrange(air_time)

#   air_time
#      <dbl>
# 1       20
# 2       20
# 3       21
# 4       21
# 5       21
# 6       21
# 7       21
# 8       21
# 9       21
#10       21
#11       21
#12       21
#13       21
#14       21
#15       21
#16       21
```

`top_n` keeps the ties hence you get more than 10 rows in both. Also, `top_n` has been superseded and replaced with `slice_min`/`max`.